# How to exclude 0-9 in perl regex

Tags: perl, regex-negation

In a comparison, I'm trying to exclude strings ending in a single numeric digit but can't get it to work.

Given:

```
@drives = ("sda", "sda1", "sda2", "sdb", "sdb1", "dm", "dm-0");
for $part (@drives)
{
    if ($part =~ /sd.[^0-9]/)
    {
        print "\tBase: $part\n";
    }
}
```

The regex `/sd.[^0-9]/` should only match on sda and sdb.  The output should be:

```
   Base: sda
   Base: sdb
```

The regex looks ok.... why doesn't it work?

Comment: `[^0-9]` matches *a single character* that is not 0-9. `sda` and `sdb` only contain 3 characters each, but your regex matches 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For once the answer is simple for a regular expression question!

Your expression `/sd.[^0-9]/` will return a *match* if `sd`, followed by any character except newline, followed by any character except ASCII `0` through `9` appears *anywhere in the string*

You must *anchor* your pattern to the start and end of the string to insist that `sd` appears at the beginning, and the non-digit character appears at the end. You should also use `.*` to allow for *zero or more* intermediate characters

This program shows the result

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my @drives = qw/ sda sda1 sda2 sdb sdb1 dm dm-0 /;

for my $part ( @drives ) {

    if ( $part =~ /^sd.*[^0-9]$/ ) {
        print "\tBase: $part\n";
    }
}
```

#### output

```
    Base: sda
    Base: sdb
```

Please note that it may well be easier and clearer to write the test like this

```
if ( $part =~ /^sd/ and $part =~ /[^0-9]$/ ) {
    print "\tBase: $part\n";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your regex won't work because of your regex try to match four character.

Use negative look ahead for to do it

```
@drives = ("sda", "sda1", "sda2", "sdb", "sdb1", "dm", "dm-0");
for $part (@drives)
{
    if ($part =~m/sd.(?!\d+)/)
    {
    print "\tBase: $part\n";
    }
}
```

Use grep with substitution  instead of for

```
@drives = ("sda", "sda1", "sda2", "sdb", "sdb1", "dm", "dm-0");
my @ac = grep{ s/(sd.)(?!\d)/\tBase : $1\n/; } @drives;
print @ac;
print "\n";
```

Comment: `grep` is for returning the elements in a list that match a condition; calling `s///` inside `grep` introduces side effects that most people wouldn't expect (i.e. changing the original array), and is less readable than a `for` loop.